# Comparing attributes and deleting duplicates in multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a jQuery script that can filter out list items based off the `href` attributes within each list item. So, if an `href` in `listOne` equals an `href` in `listTwo`, I want to add a class to the `listTwo` `li` to remove it from the list.

```
<ul id="listOne">
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="listTwo">
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
    <li><a href="somelink"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I have so far in the script:

```js
var listOneHref = $("#listOne li a").each(function(){$(this).attr("href")});

var listTwoHref = $("#listTwo li a").each(function(){$(this).attr("title")});

if (listTwoHref = listOneHref) {
    $("#listTwo ul li").addClass("hidden");
}   else {
    $("#listTwo ul li").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

The result of the above script is that the "hidden" class is added to every `li` in `listTwo`. It doesn't seem to *only* select the duplicated hrefs.

How would I write it so the script only adds the "hidden" class to the `li`s with duplicated `href`'s from `listOne` inside them?

Comment: You could create a indexed Json Object, and then put a counter on every index represented by the element id. If the counter is more than 1 then you add referenced class. E.g.: `var globalCounter = { elements: {} }; elements[li_id][element_id] = elements[li_id][element_id] +1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.each()` won't return the list you think it will; nor will using its result allow you to handle possible matches individually.

Try:

```js
$("#listOne li a").each(function() {
  var href = this.href;

  $('#listTwo li a').each(function() {
    if (href == this.href)
      $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listOne">
  <li>
    <a href="somelink"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="somelink"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="listTwo">
  <li><a href="somelink">hidden</a></li>
  <li><a href="somelink2">seen</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!